# MySQL has died. How do I recover? SOLVED

Tags: mysql

Not sure if I'm asking this in the right place. If not the right place please suggest where I may ask this.

I'm usually on stackoverflow. I noticed my websites could not communicate with mysql today. I logged into the server, couldn't see a problem and tried to restart mysql via SSH. It hung. I then rebooted the server on Hetzner. Not sure what is happening but the server is not all the way up.

I have used the hetzner rescue system to launch a minimal linux, mounted the drive and have copied all of the files from my wordpress folders, but what to do re the database? It's not running so I can't do a mysqldump. I can see the table files in /mnt/var/lib/mysql/ however. They are all ibd and frm files.

Is it possible to recover the databases from these files?

Update: booted into a rescue image, mounted the drive, cleared the mysql error and rebooted. All working again. Did not need the ibd and frm files.

Many thanks

T

Comment: I don't know what "Hetzner" is, but this sounds like something you'll need to take up with your hosting provider. (If you *are* the hosting provider, this sounds like it's more of a Stack Overflow or DBA.SE topic than a WordPress one.)

Comment: Thanks Pat. Got mariadb working again by logging in with a rescue disk and clearing the error. BAcked everything up. So all's OK now.

Comment: My edit seems to have re-opened the question. Feel free to close.